# Add Python Pandas output in a column in existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file which I am reading through pandas

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(filename.csv)
x=100*df['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True).to_frame()
print(x)
```

Here's my output

| Country |
| --- |
| US |
| France |
| Germany |

I want to save this output in a new column in the existing dataframe .How can I do that?

Comment: Your output is missing the counts, what actually do you want to assign? Do you want `df['new'] = df.groupby('Country').transform('count')`? or `df['Country'].map(100*df['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['new'] = df['Country'].map(100*df['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True))
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['US','US','France','US']})

df['new'] = df['Country'].map(100*df['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True))
print (df)
  Country   new
0      US  75.0
1      US  75.0
2  France  25.0
3      US  75.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it works for your solution

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('countries.csv')
df['New Col'] = 100*df['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True).values
df
```